# why does aws amplify api mutate give me an error?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify-sdk-android

I am newbie to aws services and i've been trying to implement Amplify.API.mutate query on android for the past two days but i am getting a weird error which i am strugging to understand and resolve .[error snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMnxb.png)

Comment: any suggestion to a solution would be appriciated .

Comment: Please don't post screenshot of text. Instead put the text in the description